# After first input not able to type next value in input field using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, material-ui, textfield

In my login form after first input not able to provide second value ex. before complete all value of text input filed existing

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

const Input = (props) => {
  const {
    autoComplete,
    type,
    value,
    error,
    // step,
    decimals,
    min,
    max,
    disabled,
    placeholder,
    rows,
    label,
    name,
    onInputChange,
    inlineElement,
  } = props;

  const _onChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === 'image') {
      onInputChange(e.target.name, e.target.files[0]);
    } else {
      onInputChange(e.target.name, e.target.value);
    }
  };

  const styles = `input-box${inlineElement ? 'inline-btn-box' : ''} ${
    error ? 'invalid' : ''
  }`;

  return (
    <div className={styles}>
      <TextField
        {...{
          label: name,
          name: name,
          onChange: useCallback((e) => _onChange(e)),
          rows: rows,
          size: 'small',
          value: value,
          variant: 'standard',
        }}
      />
      <span className='invalid-message'>{error && error[0]}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

Input.defaultProps = {
  autoComplete: 'on',
  decimals: true,
  inlineElement: null,
  rows: '4',
  step: 1,
};

export default Input;
```

The above component used in login form

login.js

```
<div className='login-form'>
                        <h2>Sign In</h2>
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <Input
                                type={'text'}
                                error={formErrors.username}
                                label={'Username'}
                                name={'username'}
                                placeholder={''}
                                value={loginFormData.username}
                                onInputChange={this.props.loginChange}
                            />
                            <Input
                                type={'password'}
                                error={formErrors.password}
                                label={'Password'}
                                name={'password'}
                                placeholder={''}
                                value={loginFormData.password}
                                onInputChange={this.props.loginChange}
                            />
                            <input
                                className='btn'
                                type='submit'
                                variant='primary'
                                value='Sign In'
                                disabled={isSubmitting}
                            />
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

action:

```
export const loginChange = (name, value) => {
    const formData = {}
    formData[name] = value
    return {
        payload: formData,
        type: LOGIN_CHANGE
    }
}
```

Comment: did you test your onChange like this? `onChange: _onChange`

Comment: yes, tested passing case

Comment: so does it work? if so i write it as answer

Comment: I mean onChange event is working for one time only after that not working.

Comment: try setting `key` for each input

Comment: tried but not working, did you tried the same.

Comment: Can you show what this.props.loginChange is. And loginFormData

Comment: export const loginChange = (name, value) => {
    const formData = {}
    formData[name] = value
    return {
        payload: formData,
        type: LOGIN_CHANGE
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Componenent inside another compoenent diclaration is not a good in react whenever state changes inside compoennt also will get re-render to avoide that we have to move inner component to outside in something below.

**Error:**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";


const { useState } = React;
function App() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([
        { value: "" },
        { value: "" },
        { value: "" },
    ]);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const Item = React.memo(({ id, value, onChange }) => {
         return (
             <div className="item">Item
                 <input
                     onChange={(e) => onChange(id, e.target.value)}
                     value={value}
                 />
             </div>
        );
    });
    const onChange = React.useCallback((id, value) => {
      setItems(items.map((item, index) => {
        return index !== id ? item : { value: value }
      }))
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <h1>Parent</h1>
            <p style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>Holds state: {count}, Does't passes to it items</p>
            <p style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>{JSON.stringify(items)}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)} style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>
                Update Parent
            </button>
            <ul className="items" style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>
                {items.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Item
                            key={index}
                            id={index}
                            value={item.value}
                            onChange={onChange}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Solution:**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

const Item = React.memo(({ id, value, onChange }) => {
  return (
      <div className="item">Item
          <input
              onChange={(e) => onChange(id, e.target.value)}
              value={value}
          />
      </div>
  );
}, []);

const { useState } = React;
function App() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([
        { value: "" },
        { value: "" },
        { value: "" },
    ]);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    
    const onChange = React.useCallback((id, value) => {
      setItems(items.map((item, index) => {
        return index !== id ? item : { value: value }
      }))
    })
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <h1>Parent</h1>
            <p style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>Holds state: {count}, Does't passes to it items</p>
            <p style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>{JSON.stringify(items)}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)} style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>
                Update Parent
            </button>
            <ul className="items" style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>
                {items.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Item
                            key={index}
                            id={index}
                            value={item.value}
                            onChange={onChange}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```